# Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/Value.php on line 100

Tags: magento

I added cms blocks in magento 2.3.4 system configuration on saving configuration I am getting error `Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/Value.php on line 100`. But same code is working fine in lower version of  magento 2.3.3.

```xml
<group id="block_footer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="45" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Bottom Block Configuration</label>
    <field id="use_cms_block_bottom" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="35" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <frontend_class>separator-bottom</frontend_class>
        <label>Use CMS Block In Bottom</label>
        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    </field>

    <field id="cms_block_bottom" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="45" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Select CMS Block</label>
        <source_model>Magento\Cms\Model\Config\Source\Block</source_model>
        <comment>You can create new CMS block in "Content > Elements > Blocks"</comment>
        <depends>
            <field id="use_cms_block_bottom">1</field>
        </depends>
    </field>
</group>
```

Comment: What did you try to resolve the issue? What is your answerable specific question?